# PowerShell - select number with decimal separator (DB2 SQL)

Tags: powershell, db2, powershell-5.0

Cannot figure out how to contain decimal separator when selecting DB2 data with PowerShell.

DB2 table contains column with item price:

```
+------+---------+
| Item |  Price  |
+------+---------+
| A    | 99,104  |
| B    | 27,05   |
| C    | 320,001 |
+------+---------+
```

This is part from Powershell script which gets this data:

```
$SQL = "SELECT Item, Price FROM Inventory"
$connection = New-Object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection
$connection.ConnectionString = "DSN=$DNS;UID=$USERNAME;password=$PASSWORD"

$connection.open() | Get-Item -ErrorAction Stop 
$cmd = New-object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand($SQL,$connection)
$result = New-Object system.Data.DataSet
(New-Object system.Data.odbc.odbcDataAdapter($cmd)).fill($result) # here comma gets removed from Price
$connection.close()

$result.Tables[0] | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter -Encoding UTF8 $OutputFile
```

This somehow selects data without decimals which is incorrect - prices are now enourmously high:

```
99104
2705
320001
```

I though that comma is removed during *Export-Csv* so added *-UseCulture*, but result is the same. It appears that comma is removed when data is selected:

```
New-Object system.Data.odbc.odbcDataAdapter($cmd)
```

My question is how can I fix this? Is there additional parameter or something is missing here?

Comment: i think it has to do with your culture settings. the "decimal" delimiter is set there [comma for some, dot for others, likely others are used]. you may need to set that delimiter or manually correct it. i don't know how to set it for just one use. [*blush*]

Comment: The problem may be in the DataSet default Locale. Try Setting the `Locale` property of the DataSet to `$result.Locale = [cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture` just before you use that.

Comment: Hi, tested with several different culture settings (da-DK, en-US, en-GB), but result is the same. (New-Object system.Data.odbc.odbcDataAdapter($cmd)).fill($result) gets decimal separator removed.

Trying to read and figure out how to add additional parameters to current code:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.odbc.odbcdataadapter?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1

Comment: What datatype is the price? What if you cast it as varchar in the select statement?

Comment: @vonPryz , I do not know datatype but CASE(Price AS VARCHAR(10)) worked, thank you!

I wonder if this can be fixed without amending SQL statement, but from PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

I cant place a comment yet.

As others asked,  what is the datatype for you price column at the database? Per your output it's left justified,  so it does not seems to be a numeric type.

Making a simple test here with PRODUCT table from db2sample database: 
And, also,  you may try to use IBM.Data.Db2 .Net provider instead of using ODBC.

```
$dbFactory = [System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories]::GetFactory('IBM.Data.DB2')
$connection = $dbFactory.CreateConnection()
$connection.ConnectionString = "Database=SAMPLE"
$connection.Open()
$da = $dbFactory.CreateDataAdapter()


$ds = new-object "System.Data.DataSet"  
$cmd = $dbFactory.CreateCommand()
$cmd.Connection = $connection

$cmd.CommandText = "SELECT PID, PRICE FROM PRODUCT"
$da.SelectCommand = $cmd 

$da.Fill($ds)
$ds.Tables[0]
```

Produces the expected decimal format.

```
PID        PRICE
---        -----
100-100-01  9,99
100-101-01 19,99
100-103-01 49,99
100-201-01  3,99


$ds.Tables[0].Columns[1].DataType

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                             
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                             
True     True     Decimal                                  System.ValueType
```

Comment: PLEASE put this in the Question. that is where all supplemental info you provide should go ...

Comment: sorry, I have not power to edit his question..  did not get your point.

Comment: arg! i misread who you are. sorry for that ... [*blush*] ///// you can get more points by taking the tour for this site. i think it is 100 points, but i am unsure of that.

Comment: ah, np @lee_dailey. It happens  ;-)